# how to display Count down clock?

Tags: android

In my application one option is there which is used to select the application trigger time that is implemented in RadioButtons like : 10 mins, 20Mins, 30mins and 60mins 
after selecting one of them the application starts at that time.. up to this working fine.
But, now I want to display a count down clock after selecting one option from above from that time onwords one clock, I want to display

That will useful to user how much time remaining to trigger the application

if any body knows about this please try to help me

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for short counts:

```
    public void timerCountDown(final int secondCount){
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {           
         public void run() {                
             if (secondCount > 0){
                 //format time and display
                 counterBox.setText(Integer.toString((secondCount)));
                 timerCountDown(secondCount - 1);
             }else{
                 //do after time is up
                 removeCounterViews();
             }
         }
         }, 1000); 
     }
```

But this one is even better and it has two events which update the main UI thread: on tick and on finish, where tick's lenght is defined in the second parameter:

```
        new CountdownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mTextField.setText("done!");
        }
     }.start();
```

Comment: how can we implements this according to the selection of radio button

Comment: on event when 10min radio button is selected use: timerCountDown(10 * 60);

Comment: Thank You for your valuable help